# Writing multiple test functions gives NullPointerException for each case except the first

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit4

I am trying to test functions of VideoStore Class which contains a array of Video type named store. When I run the test class as junit test, only first of the 4 tests passes, other throw NullPointer Exception. Each tests passes when I run them individually. I have given my test class.

I have already tried using @BeforeClass instead of @Before Annotation.
I have also tried instantiating in east @Test function separately.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import tm2.VideoStore;

public class VideoTest {
VideoStore vs;

@Before
public void before() {
    vs = new VideoStore();
    vs.addVideo("LifeOfGuy");
}

@Test
public void testAddVideo() {
    assertEquals("LifeOfGuy",vs.store[0].videoName);
}

@Test
public void testDoCheckout() {
    vs.doCheckout(vs.store[0].videoName);
    assertTrue(vs.store[0].checkout);
}

@Test
public void testDoReturn() {
    vs.doReturn("LifeOfGuy");
    assertFalse(vs.store[0].checkout);
}

@Test
public void receiveRating() {
    vs.receiveRating("LifeOfGuy", 5);
    assertEquals(5,vs.store[0].rating);
}
}
```

VideoStore Class:

```
public class VideoStore {

public Video[] store = new Video[10];
static int count = 0;

public void addVideo(String name) {
    store[count++] = new Video(name);
}

public void doCheckout(String name) {
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        if((store[i].videoName).equals(name)) {
            store[i].doCheckout();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void doReturn(String name) {
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        if((store[i].videoName).equals(name)) {
            store[i].doReturn();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void receiveRating(String name, int rating) {
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        if((store[i].getName()).equals(name)) {
            store[i].receiveRating(rating);
        }
    }
}

void listInventory() {
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Video Name | Checkout Status | Rating ");
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        System.out.println(store[i].videoName+"  |  "+store[i].getCheckout()+"  |  "+store[i].getRating());;
    }
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
}
}
```

Junit Result:----
Runs 4/4 Errors 3 Failures 0
1. testAddVideo pass
2. testDoCheckout  java.lang.NullPointerException
3. testDoReturn  java.lang.NullPointerException
4. testreceiveRating  java.lang.NullPointerException

Each one passes individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `count` variable is static so it will increase for each test and the new video will be added to a different place in the array for each test

Make it non-static

```
private int count = 0;
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, if the OP doesn't want to change it to no-static, an alternative would be to also have a counter in the test in order to keep it synced with the class counter, and access the values in the array by using the counter in the test. Or, if the tests are in the same package, access directly the class counter.

Comment: I think the failing tests proves a good example of why not to use static variables

Comment: Thanks it work ! But why doesn't the object reset after <  vs = new VideoStore(); vs.addVideo("LifeOfGuy");   >

Comment: @GaganKumar static variables lives as long as the process is running once created, they belong to the class and not to individual objects.

Comment: @K125 the object is reset, the variable is not, because it is static and thus not "attached" to the object but to the class, and the class is not "reset", it is loaded only once by the classloader.